# how to store a encrypt password in mysql in scala playframework 2.2?

Tags: scala, encryption, playframework, password-encryption, playframework-2.2

i am new at scala,I have to store user password in data in data base, so i want that it stores in a encrypted form. can anyone refer me how to the encryption in scala 2.10  play framework 2.2.*is there a way that i directly use the encryption in model function, just before the insert query of password*

Comment: The same way you'd do it in Java.

Answer (score 8):

I personally use JBCrypt (a Java library). If you'd like to use that you would add this line to your appDependencies in your Build.scala `"org.mindrot"  % "jbcrypt"   % "0.3m"`

Then in your model `import org.mindrot.jbcrypt.BCrypt`

`BCrypt.hashpw("password", BCrypt.gensalt(12))` will hash "password", which you can then bind to your SQL insert for your user. To check a password, you would retrieve the hash and use `BCrypt.checkpw(password, hash)`, which returns `true` if the given password is correct.

Comment: @LimbSoup i already mention in question that i am using play framework 2.2 and there is no build.scala file in play framework 2.2

Comment: @GovindSingh there's nothing preventing you from using a Build.scala in Play 2.2, can use that or build.sbt, or presumably both if you were so inclined (haven't tried the latter)

Comment: @GovindSingh I'm using Build.scala in Play 2.2. As virtualeyes said, you can use either that or build.sbt.

Comment: +1, You are not looking to sign a password; you want to one way hash it using a hard hash and a unique salt.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `play.api.libs.Crypto` object in the Play Framework: [http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.Crypto$](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.Crypto%24)

EDIT: As proposed by @Mark Lister, you should definitively take a look à JBcrypt.

Comment: You almost certainly don't want to sign the password.  See https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet.  JBcrypt is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing Scala / Akka and found the discussion and sample java source at

https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#javasourcecode

extremely simple and effective.